# jQuery Selector: Select Element with Specific Height

Tags: jquery, height, element, selector

I have a table. Some cells have a lot of text, and some cells have only one character.

I want to **change the width of all cells that have a height greater than or equal to 200px**.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: @Sharlike When a cell in my table has a lot of text, it heightens the row. I want it to widen the column instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">
       ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$('.cell').each(function() {
   if($(this).height()>=200)
      $(this).width(...);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Let's start by selecting the cells:

```
var $tds = $("td");
// better with a context 
// var context = "#mytable";
// var $tds = $("td", context);
```

[$.fn.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) reduces the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
function isHighterThan ($el, threshold) {
  return $el.height() >= threshold;
}

var $bigTds = $tds.filter(function () {
  return isHighterThan($(this), 200);
});
```

Finally apply a new style to matching elements.

```
$bigTds.each(function () {
  $(this).css("width", "400px");
});
```